# We have an issue with connecting Shopware 6 with the Droppery plug-in. The auth is not working, so product imports are not possible

Tags: shopware6-app

We have an issue with connecting Shopware 6 with the Droppery plug-in. The auth is not working, so product imports are not possible. Find the error log below: Can someone help us out?

Hi.

I have so many different logs

Dont know witch you want.

I add now 3 or 4 products at 17:14

2023-12-20 17:13:02

Access

95.208.107.253

200

GET /api/notification/message?limit=5&latestTimestamp=2023-12-05+06:35:56.128 HTTP/1.0

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

1.45 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:08

Access

95.208.107.253

200

GET /api/notification/message?limit=5&latestTimestamp=2023-12-05+06:35:56.128 HTTP/1.0

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

1.45 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:14

Access

95.208.107.253

200

GET /api/notification/message?limit=5&latestTimestamp=2023-12-05+06:35:56.128 HTTP/1.0

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

1.45 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:17

Access

185.244.27.132

200

POST /api/oauth/token HTTP/1.0

Import2Shop

2.12 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:17

Access

185.244.27.132

200

GET /api/sales-channel HTTP/1.0

Import2Shop

12.6 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:17

Access

185.244.27.132

200

GET /api/media-folder?filter%5Bmedia_folder.name%5D=Product%20Media HTTP/1.0

Import2Shop

2.06 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:18

Access

185.244.27.132

200

GET /api/category/018bec46abcc70179404f0ea531a8d30 HTTP/1.0

Import2Shop

4.16 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:18

Access

185.244.27.132

200

GET /api/delivery-time/018bcda7295371e69d5501fb31fcd923 HTTP/1.0

Import2Shop

1.89 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:18

Access

185.244.27.132

200

GET /api/delivery-time/018bcda7295371e69d5501fb31fcd923 HTTP/1.0

Import2Shop

1.89 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:18

Access

185.244.27.132

200

GET /api/delivery-time/018bcda7295371e69d5501fb31fcd923 HTTP/1.0

Import2Shop

1.89 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:19

Access

185.244.27.132

200

GET /api/delivery-time/018bcda7295371e69d5501fb31fcd923 HTTP/1.0

Import2Shop

1.89 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:19

Access

185.244.27.132

200

GET /api/tax HTTP/1.0

Import2Shop

2.70 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:19

Access

185.244.27.132

200

GET /api/unit HTTP/1.0

Import2Shop

1.88 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:19

Error

185.100.129.9

401

POST /api/oauth/token HTTP/1.0

1.28 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:19

Access

95.208.107.253

200

POST /api/_action/scheduled-task/run HTTP/1.0

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

1.44 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:19

Error

185.100.129.9

401

POST /api/oauth/token HTTP/1.0

1.28 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:20

Error

185.100.129.9

401

POST /api/oauth/token HTTP/1.0

1.28 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:20

Access

185.244.27.132

200

GET /api/category/018bec46abcc70179404f0ea531a8d30/children?filter%5Bcategory.name%5D=Neuheiten HTTP/1.0

Import2Shop

2.94 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:20

Error

185.100.129.9

401

POST /api/oauth/token HTTP/1.0

1.28 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:20

Access

95.208.107.253

200

GET /api/notification/message?limit=5&latestTimestamp=2023-12-05+06:35:56.128 HTTP/1.0

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

1.45 K

Apache SSL/TLS access

2023-12-20 17:13:20

Error

185.100.129.9

401

POST /api/oauth/token HTTP/1.0

A follow up with next steps!